# Add elements to 2-D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following Arrays

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
B = np.array([5,6])
```

Now I want to add the second element of A to B using the append function:

```
B = np.append(B, A[1])
```

What I want to get is:

```
B = np.array([[5, 6],[3,4]])
```

But what I get is:

```
B = np.array([5, 6, 3, 4])
```

How can I solve this? Should I use another function instead of numpy.append?

Comment: `np.vstack([B, A[1]])`?

Comment: `np.append` without `axis` flattens the arguments. Did you miss that when reading docs?  Or just ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
B = np.array([[5,6]])
B = np.append(B, [A[1]], axis=0)
print(B)
```

##### Output

```
array([[5, 6],
       [3, 4]])
```

This would be one of the way using `np.append()` specifying the `axis = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.stack` for this instead of `np.append`:

```
>>> np.stack([B, A[1]])
array([[5, 6],
       [3, 4]])
```

You could also add `[:, None]` to your two arrays and append with `axis=1`:

```
>>> np.append(B[:, None], A[1][:, None], axis=1)
array([[5, 3],
       [6, 4]])
```